# How to post on google plus using public API key (I want to post every activity generated on my site to post on my Google+ page)

Tags: python, google-plus

Is there any way to post on google plus using public api key. I dont want to go for client id and secret method as that needs user consent and I want to post every activity on google plus automatically as soon as it is generated.

I checked reading of public posts by this

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/{user_id}/activities/public?key={public API key}`

Thats working fine as expected but my need is to post on my g+ page using API key Please help me out in this or is there any third party library in python which can do the same thing for me like we do in twitter(tweepy)

Answer (score 0):

You can not automatically post `activities` to Google+ (Unless you have a Google Apps for Business account). You can either use [moments.insert](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/moments/insert) which can be inserted programmatically, or you have to use the [embeddable share button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/).

Comment: Abraham, I have google apps for business account. How can I post activities automatically using that account. I didn't find proper documentation anywhere to do this.

Comment: Google Apps has a [separate docs section](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/api/activities/insert).